# Magento Admin Dashboard graph displays "no data found" sometimes, how do I remove that?

Tags: magento, admin, charts, php

The graph/chart that appears on the frontpage of the admin panel dashboard says "No Data Found" if an order or sale hasn't been placed in the time period selected. I want to display the chart no matter what, even if there are no orders.

What do I have to modify to do this? The code or just a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `DOCROOT\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\dashboard\index.phtml` and remove lines 115-125 :

```
<div class="entry-edit" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('diagrams') ?>
                    <div id="diagram_tab_content"></div>
                <div style="margin:20px;">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals') ?>
                </div>
                <div style="margin:20px;">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('grids') ?>
                    <div id="grid_tab_content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: could you be more specific? are they the lines that say "if $this->getCount()"?

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong file.  There is no `$this->getCount()` in the file I specified.  What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I'm using magento 1.4.1.1, are you using something newer or older?